# Query a Specific Partition of a Mainframe DB2 Z/OS Table

Tags: db2, partitioning, mainframe, database-partitioning, db2-zos

I am working with a Mainframe DB2 Table Customer_Details.

```
Owner : GMMOM
Columns : Name,EmployeeNo,Salary,Age
```

Now, I have a few questions related to partitioned Tables.

1. How do I identify if a table is partitioned?
2. How do I find out the number of partitions of a Table?
3. How do I Write a Query to retrieve data from a Specific partition by providing a partition name or number reference?
4. What are the other ways to Query data from a Specific partition?

Appreciate all your support. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How do I identify if a table is partitioned?

You can retrieve this information from the DB2 catalog.  This information is irrelevant to writing a query.  Consult the IBM documentation for the structure of the DB2 catalog.

> How do I find out the number of partitions of a Table?

You can retrieve this information from the DB2 catalog.  This information is irrelevant to writing a query.  Consult the IBM documentation for the structure of the DB2 catalog.

> How do I Write a Query to retrieve data from a Specific partition by
> providing a partition name or number reference?

You don't.  Table partitioning is irrelevant to writing a query.  The DBMS handles finding the data specified in the WHERE clause of your query.

> What are the other ways to Query data from a Specific partition?

There are none.  Table partitioning is irrelevant to writing a query.  The DBMS handles finding the data specified in the WHERE clause of your query.

If your goal is to improve the performance of your query, look to your WHERE clause and/or consult your DBA.